# Load child from external page

Tags: jquery, load

Can someone help me edit this jQuery so that instead of pulling the #product_name_source from anywhere on the page it takes it from within the #Altitude div. As you can see, I've tried something there but it seems that you can't have multiple divs in a URL `http://google.com #parent #child`. Anyone able to help?

```
$('body').ready(function(){

    var product_name = 'Altitude';

    $('#product_name').load('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html #' + product_name + '#product_name_source');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').ready(function(){
var product_name = 'Altitude';

$('#product_name').load('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html' +'#product_name_source', {pName:product_name });
```

Comment: It didn't work. It just loaded everything in the `theme_info.html` file

Comment: `product_name` is passed over to the url. You can access it using `pName`

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this works.

```
$('#product_name').load('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html #' + product_name + ' #product_name_source');
```