# Load content from website into an attribute

Tags: jquery, href, attr

I need to update the `href` of a link (`#product_buy`) with a URL that can be found on another page inside the `#product_buy_source` div. Here's the jQuery.

```
$('body').ready(function(){

    $('#product_buy').attr('href', function(){
        $(this).load('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html #Altitude .product_buy_source');
    });

});
```

And here's the link that needs to be edited.

```
<a href="#" id="product_buy">Purchase</a>
```

I sense the jQuery I've used is completely wrong. Is anybody able to make it work? Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbWj4/)

Comment: Have you set up the file on the other end to allow cross-domain requests?

Comment: @Juhana It's on my domain so it shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Unless this file is also on cdn.jeremyblaze.com it does matter. The subdomain must match as well.

Comment: @Juhana Are you able to point me to a tutorial on how to do this? However I _am_ able to successfully load simple content to a div, so I think it _does_ work.

Comment: [JQuery ajax cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: @Juhana I think I've sorted this out but my code is still not working. Do you have any advice? Or know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Why do you have two ids inside the load string?

Comment: Are you passing 'Altitude' as the product name? If not, it won't work as there is the file contains just that one product. Also, your usage of ids looks incorrect. Replace with classes.

Comment: It's because the `#product_buy_source` appears numerous times on the page, but only once under the `product_name` (which in this case is 'Altitude'). But that isn't the problem because that works with a basic load to div.

Comment: @techfoobar Thanks for letting me know. I understand now. Do you have any advice on how to fix this? I actually posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245280/load-child-from-external-page/18245404#18245404) about this earlier but got no answer that worked.

Comment: It is a problem, because ids should be unique. You can't have more than one id with the same name. Use classes instead as techfoobar says.

Comment: @Juhana I've now replaced with classes

Comment: I've now also edited the question to make it simpler to understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` loads data as the `HTML` of the element it is called on. To use `.load()` (so that you could specify a selector along) for setting the `href`, you will need to to something like:

```
// load it into a temp element, and assign the href once it is loaded
$('<div/>').load('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html #Altitude .product_buy_source', function() {
    $('#product_buy').attr('href', $(this).text());
});
```

Or, in a more straightforward manner like:

```
$.get('http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/theme_info.html', function(data) {
    $('#product_buy').attr('href', $(data).find('#Altitude .product_buy_source').text());
});
```

Comment: The second one almost works! The problem is that it just adds `[object%20Object]` to the end of the current page URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JeremyBlazé - I forgot the `.text()` bit at the end. i.e. `$(data).find('#Altitude .product_buy_source'').text()` - Check the modified answer.

Comment: It's again very close but it seems to just refresh the page now.

Comment: Don't worry, I got the first one to work perfectly! Thanks for all your help!