# $.get the content of a .php file and make it the href=""

Tags: jquery, get, load

I'm trying to retrieve content from `sites/2.php` (the content is a plain text link) and put it into an `<a href="#" id="tpbx">Test</a>`, instead of the `#`. I edited the second option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250561), but it doesn't work. I also tried setting the header of `2.php` to UTF-8 by using this line of code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But that didn't help.

My code is:

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $.get('sites/2.php', function(data) {
            $('#tpb').attr('href', $(data).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the content of 2.php is generated by another (in this case not relevant) script, and could look like this:

```
<?php
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
something:?something
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$('#tpb').attr('href', data);
```

instead of

```
$('#tpb').attr('href', $(data).text());
```